# F# Set not returning the correct difference. Likely an issue with my CompareTo implementation

Tags: f#

I start with two sets, abc and zxc. "unmodified" has the correct number (1) of items. 
Set abc has two items, one of which is the unmodified item

```ml
let unmodified = Set.intersect abc zxc
let newAndModified = a - unmodified
```

I expect newAndModified to contain one item, but instead it has two. It appears to be an identical set to abc.

Even though my Set.intersect worked fine, other Set functions are not returning the right result and I believe there is something wrong with how I implemented CompareTo for this object.

```ml
type Bar =
{ Id : int
  Name : string
}

[<CustomEquality; CustomComparison>]
type Foo =
 { Name : string
   Id   : int
   Bars : Bar list
 }

 override x.Equals(y) =
   match y with
   | :? Foo as y -> x.Id.Equals y.Id
                    && x.Name.Equals y.Name
                    && x.Bars.Head.Name.Equals y.Bars.Head.Name
   | _ -> invalidArg "y" "cannot compare object to one that is not a Foo"

member x.CompareTo (y: obj) =
  match y with
  | null -> nullArg "y"
  | :? Foo as y -> x.CompareTo(y)
  | _ -> invalidArg "y" "Must be an instance of Foo"

member x.CompareTo (y: Foo) =
  match x.Equals y with
  | true -> 0
  | false -> -1

interface IComparable<Foo> with
  member x.CompareTo y = x.CompareTo y

interface System.IComparable with
  member x.CompareTo y =
    match y with
    | :? Foo as y -> (x:> IComparable<_>).CompareTo y
    | _ -> invalidArg "y" "cannot compare values of different types"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `CompareTo` implementation is definitely not going to work here. You return 0 when two objects are equal (which is good), but if they are not equal, you always return -1. This means that the first one is smaller than the last one.

However, this is not going to work. If you have objects `a` and `b`, then your comparison is saying that `a < b` and `b < a` (which is breaking the requirements on the ordering relation).

The F# set requires the objects to be orderable, because it keeps the data in a balanced tree (where smaller elements are on the left and greater are on the right) - so with `CompareTo` that always returns -1, it ends up creating a tree that makes no sense.

Why do you want to implement custom comparison for the type? I suppose you're doing that to only consider some of the fields and ignore some others. There is actually a nice trick you can do in this case, which is to create a tuple with the fields you're interested and call the built-in `hash` and `compare` functions on them. For example:

```
compare (x.Id, x.Name, x.Bars.Head.Name)
        (y.Id, y.Name, y.Bars.Head.Name)
```

This will use default F# comparison on the tuples, which is a correctly defined ordering relation.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you!!!!! You are right, I was implementing custom comparison to ignore some fields. Your answer worked like a dream. Also your reasoning for why my CompareTo implementation was not working was very well-explained!